# Saved PDF form corrupt when using pdfbox 1.8.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have updated my `PDFBOX` API Jar to `1.8.0` from `1.7.1`.

Now I'm facing some issues like, if I try to save the pdf, the saved form has been corrupted. I haven't been able to reopen the saved pdf file through pdfbox api.

Has anyone come across this so please share your views.

Answer (score 1):

please use Apache PDFBox -- Version 1.8.1. they fix few bugs. It'll fix you problem. I'm also looking what are the new feature  available in release 1.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you´ve run into this problem solved in release 1.8.1:

```
[PDFBOX-1556] - Saving a document containing a xfa form creates invalid pdf
```

I´m running 1.8.9 without any problem.